# How to deal with combinations of git aliases

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

## Problem

I have three git aliases defined in .gitconfig (with an external bash script defining a function called diff-lines):

```
    [alias]
        diffc = diff --cached
        diffnw = diff -w --ignore-cr-at-eol --ignore-all-space
        diffln =!bash -c 'source $HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines && git diff | diff-lines'
```

**How can I define 'diffln' such that I can use it in combination with other aliases?**

I'm looking for something to prevent me from having to define each version similar to:

```
    diffcln =!bash -c 'source $HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines && git diffc | diff-lines'
    diffnwln =!bash -c 'source $HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines && git diffnw | diff-lines'
    diffcnwln =!bash -c 'source $HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines && git diffnw --cached | diff-lines'
    etc...
```

#### Previous Attempts

I have tried this:
`diffln =!bash -c 'source $HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines && git $@ | diff-lines'`
and called via:
`$ git diffln diffc`
but it just gave me the default git options as if I was only calling `$ git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a something after it. Typically: `bash -c "blabla" _` or `bash -c "balbla" --`.

The first argument after `bash -c "" <here>` is `$0` - the *second* argument is `$1`.

Also remember about quoting - put `$anything` inside double quotes to prevent word splitting and filename expansions. But I am not sure how git handled that.

```
diffln =!bash -c 'source "$HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines" && git "$@" | diff-lines' _
```

if you want to have a "default" argument, you can:

```
diffln =!bash -c 'source "$HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines" && if ((!$#)); then set -- diff; fi && git "$@" | diff-lines' _
```

Comment: Thank you, the trick about adding something at the end got me most of the way to solving it. I kept getting an 'Unterminated quoted string error' so the rest of the solution was to put the whole thing in double quotes. The full working command is this (with a default option to use git diff if no argument is provided):

    diffln = "!bash -c 'source $HOME/.bash_functions/diff-lines && [ $# -eq 0 ] && git diff | diff-lines || echo "$@" | xargs git | diff-lines;' _"

Comment: `echo "$@" | xargs git` is horrible. do `git "$@"`. It's like `echo $(echo $(echo soemthing)))`.